# Calculate $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,1)} \frac{x^2+y^2-2}{|x-1|+|y-1|}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)} \dfrac{x^2+y^2-2}{|x-1|+|y-1|}$

I couldn't really see an algebriac way to see if the limit exists,so Im going to try to prove that it does not.

Consider the line $y=x$. Then we have

$$\lim_{x\to1} \dfrac{x^2+x^2-2}{|x-1|+|x-1|}=\dfrac{2x^2-2}{2|x-1|}=\dfrac{2(x+1)(x-1)}{2|x-1|}=2$$

Which other line can I consider?

Comment: Your made a slight mistake: the last limit it isn't $2$, but $\pm2$. That's it.

Comment: So showing that it can be two values, we are proved that it is not defined. When you say $\pm 2$, does that mean its $2$ AND $-2$, or either or

Comment: I meant that it it $2$ or $-2$ depending on taking $x\to1^+$ or $x\to1^-$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about along the line $x=1$.

\begin{align}\lim_{y \to 1^-} \frac{1+y^2-2}{1-1+|y-1|}&=\lim_{y \to 1^-} \frac{y^2-1}{|y-1|} \\
&=(y+1)\operatorname{sign}(y-1)\\
&=-2\end{align}

Comment: This can work I guess, but according to the comment the limit I originally had should be $\pm 2$, and so they might be the same?

Comment: yup, your approaches work, the conclusion is the limit does not exist. as the left hand side limit and right hand side limit is not equal.

Comment: So technically I can just take the line $x=1$, and show that $\lim_{y\to 1^{-}}\neq \lim_{y\to 1^{+}}$?

Comment: yup, that is sufficient, a limit is unique.

Comment: this is true. thank you